# Templates Matrix<M,N,type> c++ matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, templates

i had a different post to get help about overriding with template abstract classes and i got it working perfectly thanks to the community. Since the issue of that post is gone, i'm asking a new question :

I want to implement the multiplication, so i need different template arguments to make it work (number of rows = number of columns condition), but i can't figure out the correct way to do it.

```
#pragma once
#include "AbsMatrice.h"

template <int M, int N, typename T>

class Matrice : public AbsMatrice<M,N,T>
{

public:
    ~Matrice(){}

    //implementation de l'affichage
    void print() const  override
    {
        std::cout << "Matrice :" << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                std::cout << " " << this->m_data[i][j] << " ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    template<int O>
    Matrice<M, O, T>& mul(Matrice<N, O, T> &a) 
    {
        Matrice<M,O,T> r;
        T sum;
        for (int c = 0; c < M; c++) {
            for (int d = 0; d < O; d++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
                    sum = sum + m_data[c][k] * a(k,d);
                }

                r(c,d) = sum;
                sum = 0;
            }
        }

        return r;
    }


};
```

when using the mul function i get the error :

```
error C2100: illegal indirection
see reference to function template instantiation 'Matrice<2,2,int> &Matrice<2,2,int>::mul<2>(Matrice<2,2,int> &)' being compiled
```

thank you for the help !

PS: the () operator is working fine , and all the code that is not visible is working just fine , i'm struggling with this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple issues:

Answer to your question is that you don't want to return `*r`, you want to return just `r`.

Second issue is that `r` should be of type `Matrice<M,O,T>`.  As it is it'll be the type of the current matrix.